# What is ai_float in Cube AI

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, stm32

Lately I have started using ST's Cube AI for STM32 microprocessors and I found in the C++ code the expression `ai_float`
I imagine it is a float, but can someone give more info why this is used? and where can I find the list of types that Cube AI uses?

Answer (score 2):

yes it's float,
it's used to handle float numbers during the AI operations.
In the generated code by MX-Cube-AI  under Middlewares/ST/AI/inc/ you can find a file called ai_platform.h
In this file you can find all the datatypes used by the AI code.
ai_float is a float type in my code which is generated for STM32H7.